# 2.92 Save Crashing

Tags: export

Blender crashes when confirming the Save As in the file explorer. And also crashes when I exit out of in program windows, such as the render viewer. As soon as I click the x to go back to the main area, the entire program crashes. Without being able to render, or save, Blender isn't looking to be the program for me at the moment.

I get that this is a bug but I still need help to fix it and I don't know where to go, so before flagging it and taking it down, can you please point me in the right direction?

Any ideas on what could be causing this?

Comment: Have you looked for the [crash log](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/troubleshooting/crash.html)? An addon installed that can cause this? You can *Help -> Report a Bug...*

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post.  This question is getting close votes because it is about a bug in blender, and should be reported to the official tracker.  We are community members and not involved in development in any way.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please don't post the same question more than once. If your previous question was closed, address raised the issues by editing it, otherwise see [What should I do if no one answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers)

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know what’s causing the bugs, but you can report them on developer.blender.org one bug at a time. Read their instructions on how to do it properly, and ahead of time find a way to reproduce the bug from the default file if possible. I too have encountered crashes with 2.92, particularly when rendering smoke simulations.